# Pip updates but installs old version

Tags: python, pip

```
$ pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The problem is pretty self-explanatory.

I tell pip to update itself, it gets the 9.0.1 package, installs 8.1.1 somehow then tells me to run the command i just ran to update it.

Comment: Try reinstalling it: `sudo pip install -U --force-reinstall pip`.

Comment: Already tried it:

Comment: Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 33kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by installing pip trough the script given at the website(apt-get installs version 8.1.1):
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

It automatically uninstalled the old version so everything is in order now.

Comment: In most cases you don't want to have a global pip updated -- instead you want to use e.g. virtualenv or buildout for your projects.